# Distribution of distance traversed by ball.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

A ball is residing at the origin of an n-dimensional grid. In a specific time period, it moves along some of the axes, in the positive direction with probability p. For every direction, it remains stationary along that axis with probability 1-p. How will you describe the distribution of the distance traversed by the ball? Even if the question is ambiguous what are the possibilities from the below list?

1. Chi-squared
2. Gaussian
3. Poisson
4. Binomial

Comment: I don't understand this at all.  What does it mean to "move along some of the axes, in the positive direction?"  How can it move along more than one axis?  How can one describe anything about the distance travelled by the ball, when we aren't told *how far* in travels.  Are time and motion continuous or discrete?  Does the ball ever change direction?

Comment: There are n axes, it moves along certain fixed axes in the positive direction. I have updated the question with possible options.

Comment: Suppose $n=1$.  What is the distribution?  In the $n$ dimensional case, you have $n$ random variables with that distribution.  How can you derive the distance from them?

Comment: I think the question does not demand a clear answer and merely asks for the possibilities. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we are interested in the distribution of the distance traversed by the ball after $K$ periods. In the $j^{th}$ dimension, the distance traveled by the ball can be modelled as a binomial RV: $X_j(K) \sim B(K,p)$. The total distance traveled by the ball after $K$ periods is given by:

$X(K) = \sqrt{X_1(K)^2 + X_2(K)^2 + \;...\; + X_n(K)^2}$.

I don't know if a closed-form expression for such a function of $n$ binomial RVs can be derived. However, under suitable assumptions, one may approximate each binomial RV $X_j(K)$ with a normal RV $N(Kp, Kp(1-p))$. Under this approximation, the distance $X(K)$ will follow a non-central chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).